# Building CGO with newer Go on Travis

Tags: go, travis-ci, cgo

I need to build a Go (1.13+ due to Modules) binary with Travis. The trick is, that I need to use CGO.

Thus, I have a `language: cpp` and Focal config. The default packaged version with Travis is Go 1.11, though.

So I tried installing Go 1.13:

- using apt:

```
Setting up golang (2:1.13~1ubuntu2) ...
```

- using gimme:

```
unset GOOS;
unset GOARCH;
export GOROOT='/home/travis/.gimme/versions/go1.13.1.linux.amd64';
export PATH="/home/travis/.gimme/versions/go1.13.1.linux.amd64/bin:${PATH}";
go version >&2;
export GIMME_ENV="/home/travis/.gimme/envs/go1.13.1.env"
```

When I try to call these specific versions I get errors:

```
compile: version "go1.11.1" does not match go tool version "go1.13.1"
```

This is probably due to `PATH` and other customizations in Travis-Go since:

```
$ which go
/home/travis/.gimme/versions/go1.11.1.linux.amd64/bin/go
```

It even fails when with the same error when trying to fix `PATH` via:

```
- export PATH="/home/travis/.gimme/versions/go1.13.1.linux.amd64/bin:${PATH}"
- go build
```

Does anyone know how to override the default Travis Go version or at least reverse Travis Go-changes so that *apt* Go could be used?

**EDIT**:

Added some more example output of the Travis instance.

Comment: Your module (or one of its dependencies) defines go1.13.1 as a minimum version required to compile. Check your module file.

Comment: That is explicit and correct. That's what I mentioned in the first sentence

Comment: Well, your were not as explicit. Your assumption is correct. If you gave us the output of PATH in your specific configuration, and especially the output of `which go`, that would be a lot more helpful.

Comment: Fair enough. Tried to be more concrete now.

Comment: Not sure whether you can export the PATH. Try `- PATH="/home/travis/.gimme/versions/go1.13.1.linux.amd64/bin:${PATH}" go build`

Answer (score 0):

It of course was a very obvious workaround.

Had to also e.g. set:

```
env:
  global:
    - GOROOT='/home/travis/.gimme/versions/go1.13.1.linux.amd64'
```

Still would appreciate any solution that makes this less hacky.